# Export logging in Nodejs between files

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I have two files in nodejs :

1. `index.js`
2. `function.js`

The `index.js` is my main file in which i call the functions inside `function.js`. In `function.js` i need to use logging, the problem is i didn't figure out how to use it.

**function.js**

```
module.exports = {

Exemplfunciton: async () => {
    app.log('#### This is just an exemple im trying to run')
    }

checkCalcul:async(a,b) = > {
log.(`The Val of A : ${a}, the Val of B: ${b}`
return a+b
}
}
```

**index.js**

```
const functionToCall = require('/function.js)
module.exports = app => { 
functionToCall.Exemplfunciton()
functionToCall.checkCalcul(4,5)
}
```

Will return

> app is not defined

tried it without the app in the function.js it returned to me

> log not defined.

I only need to use the app.log between the functions ( my main one the index.js and the function.js )

Answer (score 2):

Pass as an argument

```
module.exports = app => { 
   functionToCall.Exemplfunciton(app) // add here
}
```

Then consume

```
module.exports = {
    Exemplfunciton: async (app) => { // add here
        app.log('#### This is just an exemple im trying to run')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To log in Node.js, you should use console https://nodejs.org/api/console.html

#### Example

```js
module.exports = {

ExampleFunction: async () => {
    console.log('#### This is just an example I\'m trying to run')
    }
}
```

```js
const functionToCall = require('./function.js')
functionToCall.ExampleFunction() // logs #### This is just an example I\'m trying to run
```

Comment: Sorry if you didn't understand my question, i don't want to use console.log, but i want to use the app log inside my index.js, i want to get my logging error in the server. when my functions where inside the index.js i was able to do app.log, but when i split them in two files and call them from function.js, the app log became undefined cause it only exists in index.js

Comment: Can you edit your post to include every variable you want to use? Like app.

Answer (score 0):

Consider extracting the log functionality out into its own file that can be referenced by `function.js`, `index.js`, and anything else in your app. For example:

#### logger.js

```
module.exports = {
  log: function() {
    /* aggregate logs and send to your logging service, like TrackJS.com */
  }
}
```

#### function.js

```
var logger = require(“./log.js”);d

module.exports = {
  exampleFunction: function() {
    logger.log(“foo bar”);
  }
};
```

#### index.js

```
var functions = require(“./functions.js”);
var logger = require(“./log.js”);

functions.exampleFunction();
logger.log(“foo”);
```

You should send the logs off to a service like [TrackJS to aggregate, report, and alert](https://TrackJS.com/) you to production problems.